# Difference among "Show GPU view updates" & "Show hardware layer updates"

Tags: android

I was wondering, what are the differences among

- "Show GPU view updates"
- "Show hardware layer updates"?

When we talk about [Hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), which is the option we should turn on, so that we can monitor whether "hardware acceleration" is done correctly?

p/s All the while, my understanding on "hardware acceleration" is, let GPU runs drawing code.

[image]